# PHPWord set table outer border dashed

Tags: phpword

I need to set outer table border only without inner borders and set it dashed in PHPWord library.

```
    $tableStyle = [
        'borderSize' => 6,
    ];

    $phpWord->addTableStyle('myTable', $tableStyle);

    $table = $section->addTable('myTable');
```

Now I have that code. It set table to inner cells too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I read the `table`-documentation, `borderSize` is a cell-specific style-option;

It looks like you can achieve what you want by manipulating the `section` the table is a child element of, introducing such a section if it isn't present already (according to the documentation it should be mandatory/implicit).

Alternatives to achieve your visual goals might be `valign` or `margin` section options.

The manipulation of the line-style of tables isn't documented -- `line`-elements have the `dash` option with possible values of `dash, rounddot, squaredot, dashdot, longdash, longdashdot, longdashdotdot`, maybe you just try to set this in the `$tableStyle`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Knew that could be done with cells. Thought that maybe you can apply it to whole table. At the end implemented with cell styles.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct @Tom Regner, `borderSize` is a cell-specific style-option; so if you add that into a `tableStyle` and apply it to the cells then table borders will appear as per the size.

```
$requestorContactTbl = $section2->addTable('requestorContactTbl', [
    'borderSize' => 6, 
    'borderColor' => 'F73605', 
    'afterSpacing' => 0, 
    'Spacing'=> 0, 
    'cellMargin'=> 0
]);

$requestorContactTbl->addRow();

$requestorContactTbl
    ->addCell(9999, [
        'borderSize' => 6
    ])
    ->addText('Administration Request', [
        'name' => 'Arial',
        'size' => '12',
        'color' => 'FFFFFF',
        'bold' => true,
        'italic' => true
    ]);
```